# Using node module bignum in a node-red flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I am trying to use the node module bignum in a function in a node-red flow. I have installed the node module in the same folder as settings.js. I have edited settings.js to include

```
functionGlobalContext: {
   bignum:require('bignum')
},
```

and my function looks like this

```
var bignum = context.global.bignum;

var b = bignum('782910138827292261791972728324982')
    .sub('182373273283402171237474774728373')
    .div(8)

msg.payload = b;

return msg;
```

For some reason it returns only this

```
[msg.payload] : object
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bignum is being passed as msg.payload, it's just not being rendered properly in the debug panel

This can be checked with the following flow

```
[{"id":"4559ab0b.848204","type":"function","name":"","func":"var bignum = context.global.bignum;\n\nvar b = bignum('782910138827292261791972728324982')\n    .sub('182373273283402171237474774728373')\n    .div(8);\n\nmsg.payload = b;\n\nconsole.log(\"%j\", msg.payload);\nconsole.log(\"%j\", b);\nconsole.log(b);\nconsole.log(\"%j\", msg);\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":413,"y":186,"z":"6dffe97f.085fd8","wires":[["152e806f.249de8"]]},{"id":"28153711.bd78f","type":"inject","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":203,"y":140,"z":"6dffe97f.085fd8","wires":[["4559ab0b.848204"]]},{"id":"62001fd9.03c0c8","type":"debug","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":712,"y":191,"z":"6dffe97f.085fd8","wires":[]},{"id":"152e806f.249de8","type":"function","name":"","func":"console.log(\"2\");\nconsole.log(msg.payload);\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":543,"y":256,"z":"6dffe97f.085fd8","wires":[["62001fd9.03c0c8"]]}]
```

I would open an issue to have this looked at [here](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues)

---

UPDATE

This is most likely because bignum does not implement a toString method so Node-RED doesn't know how to render the output. The best way to get this fixed is probably to raise a issue with bignum not Node-RED.

---

UPDATE 2

Node-RED issue has most up to date info

https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/690

Comment: Thanks for the console logging help. This works if you change msg.payload to `message.payload = b.toString();`